# Export rows from database to csv file

Tags: java, oracle, export-to-csv, resultset

I want to export a huge amount of data (a few millions of rows) from my database to csv file using java. In this moment I iterate over the result set, I add the rows in a List and after each 1000 rows I write the lines to the file and I clear the list.

In this moment I spend about 50 seconds to export 500 000 lines. Is there any other faster way to make this export?

Comment: not sure how much this will help but pre-define size in list `new ArrayList(1000);`

Comment: or add lines to StringBuilder and at the end of result add "\n", in one go write this to file, it would be better if you had posted code along with question, to help SO members to try.

Comment: I believe you are using JDBC. Please add your current code.

Answer (score 3):

Open Toad and connect to the database.
Then click on the menu Database > Editor, to open the SQL editor window.
In SQL editor window, type your SQL query and press Ctrl+Enter to execute and get the results in a grid. Below is an example of an SQL query.

```
 SELECT cust_first_name,
           cust_last_name,
           cust_city,
           cust_state_province,
           cust_main_phone_number
      FROM sh.customers
     WHERE country_id = '52775' AND cust_valid = 'A';
```

Then right-click on the Grid in Toad and from the shortcut menu select Export Dataset option.
In the Export Data window, select the options as shown in below image to export the data into CSV file from Toad. Select the option Delimited Text from the Export Format drop-down. Specify the file location and name in File field. Specify the delimiter and click OK to export.

[image: Export CSV from toad]

Comment: really helpful, you saved my day (y)

Answer (score 0):

I used the method .setFetchSize(1000) from Prepared Statement and I could to export about 4 million of rows in about 40 seconds.

Maybe will be useful and for somebody else. :D